# jar ignores my manifest

Tags: java, jar, manifest, manifest.mf

Jar is ignoring my manifest file and replaces it with auto-generated manifest.

my manifest is :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Created-By: Student Name 
Main-Class: ua.sumdu.j2se.studentName.tasks.PrintMonth
```

(with empty line)

cmd:

```
jar -cvf build/tasks.jar MANIFEST.MF build\classes\ua\sumdu\j2se\studentName\tasks\*.class
```

and as a result if I open jar file with winrar, there would be:

```
build
META-INF
MANIFEST.MF - my manifest
```

if i place manifest into META-INF and execute

```
jar -cvf build/tasks.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF build\classes\ua\sumdu\j2se\studentName\tasks\*.class
```

in my META-INF folder will be 2 manifests.

What's going on?

Answer (score 9):

Use the `M` option to disable the default `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, or use the `m` option to explicitly specify your own ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)).

Answer (score 4):

One more thing: the order of `jar` options matters. If you put `m` first, `f` second, then `jar` arguments need to go in the same order: `manifest-file jar-file`, and vice versa.

The line in jar help I missed first:

```
The manifest file name, the archive file name and the entry point name are
specified in the same order as the 'm', 'f' and 'e' flags.
```

Answer (score 3):

Also check that the last line of your manifest ends with a new line or carriage feed. I did not have a new line at the end of my manifest and this made it appear to be omitted.

I see you have (with empty line). But I arrived at this answer without one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `jar -cmvf MANIFEST.MF build/tasks.jar build\classes\ua\sumdu\j2se\studentName\tasks\*.class`

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.**

Compile `Main.java`.

```
javac Main.java
```

**Step 2.**

Create `MANIFEST.MF`.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

**Step 3.**

Create `app.jar`.

```
jar cmvf MANIFEST.MF app.jar Main.class
```

**Step 4.**

Run `app.jar`.

```
java -jar app.jar
```